# Paypal - When I verify a mobile payment, it returns HTTP 404 error

Tags: java, android, paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal on Android. After payment is successfully, I do the server-to-server call for verify payment.
(Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)
However, if I using the following command in Linux to test, it returns 404 error. I already change {accessToken} to right value. Is anything I miss why I always get 404 error. Even I use the http testing tool (http://www.hurl.it/), it get the same result. Anyone can give me a tip ?

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}"
```

Comment: Have you been successfully able to [create a payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment) and [retrieve it later](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource)? These docs may be helpful https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Comment: @AviDas I think I already finish a simulated payment. Steps are: I try the android demo app on my device and I get id = PAY-1CH415761F1235919KIQMTGY. Then, i use client id and secret id to get the access token. According to document suggest, we need to verify a mobile payment by our server, however, I use the curl command above and get 404 error. the example command is from paypal, that's why i feel strange why i got 404 error. Could you any ideas about it ?

Comment: Paypal server return:

    {"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "message":"The requested resource ID was not found",
    "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "debug_id":"0bdcbfbef58e9"}

Comment: You are sure that you are using the same client_id and client_secret and environment i.e. sandbox on both mobile and later to get the access token? If you are able to go through the [full payment flow](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) with your credentials on sandbox, it should work on mobile sdk as well. Also try logging into your api.sandbox.paypal.com with your sandbox account to see if the payments are getting registered there.

Comment: @AviDas 
(1) I already create a sandbox account (personal) to test, I make a purchase on mobile phone, so I think I don't need to create a "PayPal payment request" on server. I only get the access token. Is it something wrong ?
(2) I assign a balance for my testing account 1000 USD, however, after i make a purchase, then I check my balance in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com. I found my balance is still 1000 USD and no any activity. Is it normal ? or I miss something ?
PS: I got client_id and secret when I create a APP, so i think it's fine.